# MesonBuild: How to define dependency to a library that cannot be found by `pkg-config`?

Tags: c, dependencies, meson-build

My project (in C) has a third party dependency at build time. But the third party library is, by default, installed to `/opt/` instead of `/lib`, and I cannot find it in `pkg-config`. From `mesonbuild`'s documentation, should I use `declare_dependency`, I don't have its source code to treat it as my sub-project. If I use `dependency()` to define it, I can't find the correct argument to define a customized location.

How to declare dependency for a non-standard third party library?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As documented [here](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#declare_dependency) and [here](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#dependency)

> The main use case for this [`declare_dependency()`] is in subprojects.

and

> [`dependency()`] finds an external dependency ... with `pkg-config` [or] library-specific fallback detection logic ...

You can, instead, use [`find_library()`](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#compiler-object) provided by the `compiler`
object and [`include_directories()`](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#include_directories) .  `find_library()` returns an object just like the one `declare_dependency()` returns.  `include_directories()` returns an opaque object which contains the directories.

Assuming you are using a C compiler and your 3rd party library and its header file are `/opt/hello/libhello.so` and `/opt/hello/hello.h`, you can do:

```
project('myproj', 'c')

cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
lib_hello = cc.find_library('hello',
               dirs : ['/opt/hello'])
inc_hello = include_directories('/opt/hello')
exec = executable('app',
                  'main.c',
                  dependencies : [lib_hello],
                  include_directories : inc_hello)
```

Comment: I get error - `Search directory opt/hello is not an absolute path.`. Any idea?

Comment: Assuming from the error message, did you forget to add the leading `/`?

Comment: I am not after `/opt/hello` as I'm on Windows. I just want to comment that for some reason `dirs` requires absolute path.

Comment: And if libhello has one million dependencies already specified by pklf-config you just happily replicate that configuration in your project? Not convinced by this approach in general.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to `meson` object [here](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#meson-object) : **current_source_dir()** method returns a string to the current source directory.

Use it for the case `libhello.so` and `libhello.h` are located in 
`<workspace>/hello` directory

```
<workspace>/main.c
<workspace>/meson.build

<workspace>/hello/libhello.so
<workspace>/hello/libhello.h
<workspace>/hello/meson.build
```

In `<workspace>/hello/meson.build`:

```
lib_hello = cc.find_library('hello', dirs : meson.current_source_dir())
```

In `<workspace>/meson.build`:

```
project('myproj', 'c')
subdir('hello')

inc_hello = include_directories('./')
exec = executable('app',
                  'main.c',
                  dependencies : [lib_hello],
                  include_directories : inc_hello)
```