# Link Against Existing `.lib` File in Meson Build on Windows

Tags: windows, build, meson-build

I'm building a simple project in [Meson Build](https://mesonbuild.com).
While it is well documented [how to create a dependency](https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html) in Meson Build Documentation (With implicit assumption of UNIX / LINUX system) it is not clear how to link against arbitrary not on path library.

Let's I have the following project on Windows:

```
- ProjectFolder
    -   SrcFiles
        -   SrcFile1.c
        -   SrcFile2.c
    -   Lib
        -   MyLib1.lib
        -   MyLib2.lib
```

I want to create an executable based on `SrcFile1.c` and `SrcFile2.c` which is linked against **pre built** `MyLib1.lib` and `MyLib2.lib`.

What is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found solution on MesonBuild: [How to define dependency to a library that cannot be found by `pkg-config`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010355)? on [Yasushi Shoji's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47027944/195787).

The only issue the `dirs` property requires Absolute Path.
Hence this is a sketch of what can be done:

```
# Constants
projectDir  = meson.current_source_dir() # MESON_SOURCE_ROOT
buildDir    = meson.current_build_dir() # MESON_BUILD_ROOT

lib1Path = join_paths(projectDir, 'Lib')
lib2Path = join_paths(projectDir, 'Lib')

objCCompiler = meson.get_compiler('c')

MyLib1 = objCCompiler.find_library('MyLib1', dirs : lib1Path)
MyLib2 = objCCompiler.find_library('MyLib1', dirs : lib1Pat2)
```

Now just to define the target build with the proper dependencies.